# Weird tags in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a trouble with IE8, (in last versions works perfect). IE add two tag (`<div>` and `<img>`) in each tabs after first. In first tab all is good. 
img tag has src='undefined' I have tried to hide when user click on tab but resultless.

```
$('.tabLinks').click(function() {

   $('img[src="undefined"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');

});
```

When viewed source - it is has no contain tags mentioned above

Maybe someone faced with it. Will be glad for any help.

Attach screens bellow:
[Screen 1](http://s13.postimg.org/zau24fsx3/image.jpg)

When I tried to find in developer's tool I saw two tags, but I don't know why and how IE insert it after each generated in template tags. In all others browsers no problem at all. Just only here.

[Screen 2](http://s16.postimg.org/40qemo1f9/image.jpg)

**UPD**
Relevant code:

```
{{foreach (#Core.$data.content.pages as $pageName => $pageValues)}}
<div id="{{$pageName}}">
    <div class="subbg">
        <div class="column">
            {{foreach ($pageValues as $default => $param)}}
            {{if ($default == 'defaults')}}
            {{foreach ($param as $pk => $pv)}}
            <div class="undercover" id="underCover-{{$pageName}}"
                 productelementid="{{if (!isSet($pv.productElementId))}}0{{else}}       {{$pv.productElementId}}{{/if}}"
                 side="{{$pageName}}"
                 style="
                    position: relative;
                    width:{{$pv.bwidth}}px;
                    height:{{$pv.bheight}}px;
                    border:2px solid #C4C4C4;
                    margin:{{$pv.bleeding}}px;
                    background-color:{{if (!isSet($pv.color))}}#ffffff{{else}}{{$pv.color}}{{/if}};
                    overflow:hidden;">
                <div id="sub-{{$pageName}}" class="substrate PageElements"
                    type="substrate"
                    side="{{$pageName}}"
                    style="position: absolute;
                           top:12px;
                           left:12px;
                           width:{{$pv.width}}px;
                           height:{{$pv.height}}px;
                           background-color:transparent;
                           border:2px dotted #cccccc;
                           z-index:100;"></div>
            {{foreach ($pageValues as $pType => $pageValue)}}
                {{if ($pType == 'label')}}
                    {{foreach ($pageValue as $labelK =>$labelV)}}
                    <!-- Print label elemnets B-->
                    <div id="{{$labelV.html_id}}"
                        class="PageElements"
                        type="{{$pType}}"
                        side="{{$pageName}}"
                        content="{{$labelV.content}}"
                        fontId="{{$labelV.font_id}}"
                        name="{{$labelV.html_id}}"
                        style="position:absolute;
                            top:{{$labelV.posY}}px;
                            left:{{$labelV.posX}}px;
                            color:{{$labelV.color}};
                            font-family:{{$labelV.font_family}};
                            font-size:{{$labelV.font_size}}px;
                            font-weight:{{$labelV.font_weight}};
                            font-style:{{$labelV.font_style}};
                            text-decoration:{{$labelV.text_decoration}};
                            text-align:{{$labelV.text_align}};
                            line-height:{{$labelV.line_height}}px;
                            width:{{$labelV.width}}px;
                            height:{{$labelV.height}}px;
                            z-index:{{$labelV.zIndex}};
                            overflow:hidden;"
                        >
                        {{$labelV.content}}
                    </div>
                    <!-- Print label elemnets E-->
                    {{/foreach}}
                {{/if}}
                {{if ($pType == 'image')}}
                    {{foreach ($pageValue as $imageK =>$imgV)}}
                    <!-- Print image elemnets B -->
                    <div id="{{$imgV.html_id}}"
                        class="PageElements"
                        type="{{$pType}}"
                        side="{{$pageName}}"
                        name="{{$imgV.html_id}}"
                        path="{{$imgV.path}}"
                        style="position:absolute;
                            top:{{$imgV.posY}}px;
                            left:{{$imgV.posX}}px;
                            z-index:{{$imgV.zIndex}};
                            background-image: url('{{$imgV.path}}');
                            background-repeat: repeat-x;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            background-size: cover;
                            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                            src='{{$imgV.path}}',
                            sizingMethod='scale');
                            -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                            src='{{$imgV.path}}',
                            sizingMethod='scale');
                            width:{{$imgV.width}}px;
                            height:{{$imgV.height}}px;
                            overflow:hidden;"
                    ></div>
                    <!-- Print image elemnets E -->
                    {{/foreach}}
                {{/if}}
            {{/foreach}}
            </div>
            {{/foreach}}
            {{/if}}
            {{/foreach}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/foreach}}
```

Comment: What do you mean IE is adding tags?

Comment: I assume this is done by some `jQuery` plugin. Try to disable and inspect again.

Comment: each browser render invalid HTML by its own, i think your HTML is invalid somewhere... Could you post the code relevant to these TAGS?

Comment: please see second link to image. There you can see two tags div with z-index:-1 and image with src='undefined'. I didn't write it. When see source of page it is doesn't exist too but in developer's tool appears

Comment: I have just posted relevant code

Comment: @Morpheus, yes, I right. If turn off JQ, problem disappear.